# How come when I use guess_type I get a different answer than types_map

Tags: python, mime-types

```
In [14]: mimetypes.guess_type('file.tgz')[0]
Out[14]: 'application/x-tar'

In [15]: mimetypes.types_map['.tgz']
Out[15]: 'application/gzip'
```

Why do I get two different answers?

Answer (score 0):

The second element of the result of `mimetypes.guess_type()` is the encoding. In this case it *would* be `"gzip"`, but you've thrown it out. The file itself *is* a gzip file, but it is also a tar file compressed with gzip.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with x-tar is it is set inside Content-Type. This causes Google Chrome to download the file with wrong file type (.tgz gets downloaded as .tar). When I use mimetypes.add_type('application/gzip', '.tgz') it doesn't override it